# How to write number using fileoutputstream

Tags: java

I'm new to java , i need to define counter then write the result in a file

```
int counter=0;
int resultstweets=0;
fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(
prop.getProperty("PATH_TO_OUTPUT_FILE")));
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("path/of/file")); 
while ((tweetJson = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String result = drpc.execute(TOPOLOGY_NAME, tweetJson);
    Status s = null;
    try {
        s = DataObjectFactory.createStatus(tweetJson);
        result = s.getId() + "\t" + s.getText() + "\t" + result;
        //   this is my counter 
        resultstweets+=counter;
    } catch (TwitterException e) {
        LOG.error(e.toString());
    }
    fos.write(result.getBytes());
    fos.write(newLine);
}
fos.write(newLine);
fos.write("Finish: ".getBytes());
fos.write("resultstweets".getBytes());
fos.write(newLine);
// here i write it in the file 
fos.write(resultstweets);
```

but what i got at the end of file

```
Finish: resultstweets
**\001**459202139258
```

Comment: Wrap the `FileOutputStream` in a `BufferedOutputStream` so you can write `String`s directly, without `getBytes()` everywhere.

Comment: i tried and got The method write(int) in the type FileOutputStream is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Comment: @AndyTurner: he wants a `Writer`, not an `OutputStream` for writing textual data.

Comment: Try `fos.write((resultstweets + "").getBytes());`.

Comment: Code in your question has been edited. In the future, please strive to post only well-formatted code. If you want the volunteers here to put in the effort to read and understand your code, then it's certainly not asking too much of you to put in the effort to make sure that it's formatted appropriately.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels sorry for that , i didn't mean it thanks

Comment: @saka1029 thanks i guess it worked but counter is zero although file has data

Comment: @GregKopff ofc, I was asleep at the keyboard. I meant `BufferedWriter`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method `java.io.FileOutputStream.write(byte[] b)` you're using in your last line gets a byte array as parameter.

So you should first convert your `integer` to `string` and then call `getBytes` on that:

```
fos.write(String.valueOf(resultstweets).getBytes());
```

You can find a proper example of using this method [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-write-to-file-in-java-fileoutputstream-example/).

Comment: It is another problem... In your code counter is initialized with zero and then never changed.

Comment: i defined counter with intialized value then used this line     resultstweets+=counter; to increase it after each tweet readen from br which is buffer reader reads from file

Comment: may i write another  post for this problem !

Comment: What `resultstweets+=counter;` does is assigning 0 + 0 to `resultstweets` in each line, which doesn't change its value so maybe if you initialize counter with 1 you can get your desired result.

Comment: Many Many thanks it worked after a week beacuse of my wrong intalizations , thanks again i defined it int counter = 1;
   int resultstweets = 0;